# Pattern matching in a column in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pattern-matching

MY requirement is to find out all the column values where there are spaces in between them.

e.g. My values are  'aa  bb  cc', 'aa    bbcc', 'aabb cc'.
Ideally they are all same if you exclude space in between them!
How do I find out all these type of columns from a table using query or any sort of mechanism.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first paragraph just says you're looking for values with spaces. The second paragraph suggests you're looking for values that are the same if you ignore the spaces, but not what you want to do with them - are you looking for duplicates, counting while ignoring the spaces, something else?

Comment: yes. You are right. I am looking for duplicates barring spaces

Comment: Do you need a single row or the list of all duplicate rows? in your example, do you expect one aggregate row or all the three rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `REPLACE()` with `EXISTS()` like this :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable s
             WHERE replace(t.YourCol,' ','') = replace(s.YourCol,' ','')
              and t.YourCol <> s.YourCol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the spaces from your strings and then use the result to aggregate:

```
create table dupTest  ( val varchar2(16));

insert into dupTest values ('aa bb cc');
insert into dupTest values ('aa bbcc');
insert into dupTest values ('aabb cc');
insert into dupTest values ('aaBB cc');
insert into dupTest values ('a a B B c c');
insert into dupTest values ('C C B B C C');

SQL> select replace(val, ' ', '') as no_space_string,
  2         count(1) as num
  3  from dupTest
  4  group by replace(val, ' ', '')
  5  having count(1) > 1; -- only values with more than one occurrence

NO_SPACE_STRING       NUM
-------------------- ----
aabbcc                  3
aaBBcc                  2
```

Comment: I think he want all the rows where the trimmed value is not unique, not the unique values..

Comment: @Sagi: Maybe you're right, but the question is not that clear; just added a comment for the OP, hoping for a clearer needed result